# Node.js for Backend

Tags: node.js, api, bots, backend, mern

What is the best way to learn practical Node.js?
I want to be a Node.js developer.
All the courses I found on the Internet (paid or unpaid) seems to have little to very basic knowledge of Node.
These courses are unable to full fill my thirst for knowledge.
Kindly recommend me a good source to learn Node.js.
Yes I am asking for your Opinion.

Comment: Asking recommendations for courses is off-topic, same way is opinion based questions like what is the best way to learn something.

Comment: @JamesZ thank you for your help. Your comment was as useful as 'ueue' in Queue.

Answer (score 1):

Read the documentation and learn the best practices. Once you learn to control the flow, you can do anything with it. My suggestion would be to find a problem statement and try to solve that using Node.